# Issues with MySql replication on MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have been trying to get MySQL replication set up on digital ocean with forge servers & Maria DB.

I keep getting this error when running slave status\g :

Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).

This is the tutorial I followed:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

I've checked the server-id in both my.conf files and the master is set to 1 and the slave 2.

Here's a dump of the full status\g output

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

`*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: ***** 
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3306 
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mariadb-bin.000017 
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 642 
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002 
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4 <br>
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mariadb-bin.000017
             Slave_IO_Running: No 
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes 
              Replicate_Do_DB:

          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 1 
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 642 
              Relay_Log_Space: 249 
              Until_Condition: None 
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0 
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No 
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL 
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No 
                Last_IO_Errno: 1593 
                Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MySQL server ids; these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it). 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0 
               Last_SQL_Error:

  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
                   Using_Gtid: No 
                  Gtid_IO_Pos: 
      Replicate_Do_Domain_Ids: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Domain_Ids: 
                Parallel_Mode: conservative`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the config file is being used.  It is probably `/etc/my.cnf` (not `my.conf`).

Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';` on both servers.

Check that `server_id` is in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Have ran the show variables command on both servers and they return 1 and 2  as they should, also checked the location of the server_id value in the config file and it is within the [mysqld] section. Is there anything else I can check? (The conf file being used is my.cnf not my.conf that was my mistake).

Answer (score 0):

In my case，I have determined that different nodes are configured with different servers_id

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';
```

Then, the replication was reconfigured ...

```
stop slave;
reset slave;
change master to ...
start slave;
```